# Not able to see Recycler View

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, navigation-drawer, toolbar

**Please check the XML code :-**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar1"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_standalone" />
</LinearLayout>
<!--    Navigation View Describe here input are header and toolbar-->
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:itemIconTint="#8C000000"
    app:itemTextColor="#E6000000"
    app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation">

</com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>


<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/drawerLayout"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> Hi Guys,
>
> I am not see my Recycler view in following XML. Could you help me guy. Please let me know where I need to change my code so I am see Recycler view in mine page. Thanks in Advance for your help. Is there any change in layout required or any change in XML code required, in mine there is toolbar and Navigation drawer both are there. please help

Answer (score 0):

you have change your recyclerview **width** to **match_parent**  or **wrap content**

Answer (score 0):

this line looks suspicous... (`RecyclerView` attr)

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/drawerLayout"
```

try to exchange it with

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

still `DrawerLayout` should be root of your XML file and contain two `View`s - first one will be your content, second one will be sliding panel. both may be some `ViewGroup`s (e.g. `ConstraintLayout` or `RecyclerView`) which may contain more complex `View` structures. proper structure should look like this:

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

    <!-- content frame -->
    <LinearLayout>
        <include toolbar/>
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- navigation/sliding from side view -->
    <LinearLayout>
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView/>
    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

some doc and sample in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui)

Comment: changes went fine . but now toolbar come above recycler view

Comment: check out my edit. you didn't described where this `RecyclerView` should be placed... some sketch may be useful how your layout should look with side panel hidden and visible